# Is many layouts on one page bad in nativescript? And if so why?

Tags: layout, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I wonder if i can use many layouts in Nativescript, exempel many GridLayouts on one page?  I have not found any source that says it is bad with many layouts. I have only heard that it does so the app gets bad performance. So if it gets bad performance, what will happen? And is it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, compounding with a lot of layouts can be a problem and generates a performance penalty.

Always try to flattened your layouts, keep it simple. A good start point is to consider a GridLayout to do the job, but Nativescript has 7 layouts at your disposal, so we always have cards to choose the best for that page/screen.

See this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U191esT9_zY&list=PLaZ5nRwWA4Bha-dRy9CoUkQdYLLyCGKUj&index=2&t=0s) about layouts by Brad Martin, will clarify some aspects that you ask.

Comment: Alright okey. But what will happen? Will the app crash? I have some pages where i have like 10 gridlayouts.

Comment: Probably you will face some slow transitions, the screen could have longer loading, this kind of stuff.

But you can go on Developer options on your device (real or AVD) and turn on some metrics to get some grounds.

I my opinion, you need to create a lot of nested and complex layouts to have this sort of problem.